# Parallel NSTimers multithreading

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have two NSTimers that are supposed to run parallel one from the other. Each timer control a specific part of the UI (`Timer1` = UI A, `Timer2` = UI B). `UI A` and `UI B` change whenever its respective timers get to X interval. However, in order to make the change, `UI A`nees to check `UI B`'s state.

When I run the two NSTimers, there's a 1 second delay between them:

```
    firstSemaphoreTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(firstTimerTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    secondSemaphoreTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(secondTimerTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

How can I sync those two timers using threads? Or what approach you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two timers. You can process both tasks with one timer.

```
NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
// ...
-(void)tick:(sender)id{

void(^processBlock)(void)= ^{
    // process UI 1 and 2     
};
if([NSThread isMainThread]){
    processBlock();
}else{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), processBlock);
}
}
```

Even with two timers, you can't update UI concurrently since it's done on main queue. If there is anything else to be done after updating UI that is dependent on it, you can always dispatch the block synchronously by calling dispatch_sync.

Comment: If I *need* to use multithreading, what would be the right approach? Think of the behaviour as one of a semaphore.

Comment: As I said, you can only update UI on main queue. You can't do it using multithreading.

Comment: I mean, running `Process A` and `Process B` on different threads, and updating the UI on the main thread...

Comment: @OscarSwanros Why do you need to run `A` and `B` on separate threads?  In any case, you should use queues or simply `dispatch_async()` to one of the global concurrent queues.   Or ask a new question that describes better what you are actually trying to do.